# An icon for surname field?

Tags: forms, icons

While designing form I've found out that I'm totally stuck at choosing icon for the surname field. Actually, the surname is so abstract notion and doesn't really differ from name in its sense, so I'm really confused about choosing an icon.
Personally I would make no icons for such fields, but it's kinda demand.
Maybe, someone has already been in such a situation and could share same ideas and experience?

Comment: How about a family crest icon? If might look a little too much like a shield, but it may work!

Comment: The idea of 'surname' is itself problematic when you are programming for the real world. You might be interested in reading more on this: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 2):

The best icon is a text label. Also check: [Should icons be used to represent "name" and "surname" in a form?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/73886/should-icons-be-used-to-represent-name-and-surname-in-a-form)

Comment: I agree that label > icon. But as I've said, it's a demand to use only icons and placeholders

Comment: You can try with a "dog tag" icon. https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios7-line-strategy-2/512/token-512.png

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an instance where you need to push back on the client. Find out why they want icons, then create a couple of prototypes: one using labels, one using their suggested icons. Test with users, and ideally let the clients see the testing take place so they can see the problems.